# Removing duplicates in a query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, duplicates

I have a view with more than 20 columns.

I have the following situation:

**TABLE X**

```
Column A | Column B | Column C

   CA1   |   CB2    |   CC7
   CA2   |   CB2    |   CC8
   CA3   |   CB3    |   CC5
   CA4   |   CB4    |   CC6
```

How can I do the following query?

- Show only 3 rows (`CA1`, `CA3` and `CA4`) because I need to remove the row `CA2` by the following conditions:

  1. `CB2` is duplicated in `Column B`
  2. `CC7` is different than `CC8` in `Column C`

The select has more than 20+ columns too, I could not (maybe my fault) do a distinct or group by.

I tried to cross it with itself but also doesn't work because join two times the same record on the second query.

Please advise! thanks!

Comment: How/why do you give CA1 a preference over CA2? It violates the same two conditions that CA2 does.
It might be more helpful if you give a simplified structure of the tables you're joining/querying on.

Comment: CC5 is different than CC6 on Column C, so why do you want CA4 returned?

Comment: @Beth I correct the CA4, sorry.

Comment: @VinodVishwanath Because on the data, the real value of CC8 is zero

Comment: If you want to exclude zeroes, you can put that in the WHERE clause?

Comment: yes but I've another one records that I wont remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT 
   mina.colB, 
   mina.min_a, 
   tblx.colC
FROM  tblx INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    colB, 
    MIN(colA) AS min_a
    FROM  tblx
GROUP BY
    colB
) mina ON 
mina.min_a = tblx.colA AND 
mina.colB = tblx.colB
```

or you could use max(colc) instead of min(colA), if that's how you want them selected